# Is is possible to order my posts by recency?

Tags: support, profile-page

I have quite a few posts, but my problem is that the oldest posts show first. Can I order my posts so the newest ones show up first? Or is that not possible? If it isn't possible, can this be added?

Comment: I read the title as "Is it possible to order my posts by regency?" and I was wondering what the regency of a post could be.

Comment: @kiam It would be ordering your posts by "The office or period of government by a regent." :-)

Comment: I did a bit of a double-take at first also, but then I thought: "recency – what a terrific word". A new one on me, but one to note (even if it doesn't seem to be in the dictionary – it should be, though).

Comment: @DublinJimbo Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should see buttons that let you do this.
Try clicking `recent`.

[image]

Comment: Can I make that default?

Comment: It should persist. Setting it once will make it automatically use that the next time.

Comment: Thanks! It stays ordered by recency.